# If $f$ and $g$ are bijective functions, prove that $(g \circ f)' = f' \circ g'$

Tags: elementary-set-theory, proof-verification

I'm starting to write proofs and would love some feedback on my version to prove the above:

Define $f: X \rightarrow Y$ and $g: Y \rightarrow Z$ as bijective functions. We can also define $x$ as the unique $x\in X$ such that $f(x)=y$ maps to a unique $y\in Y$ and $z$ as the unique $z\in Z$ such that $g(y)=z$.

By the definition of $f$ and $g$ as bijective, they are invertible functions so $f'(g'(z)) = x$. Here $'$ signifies the inverse.

Since $(g \circ f )(x) = g(f(x)) = z$ is bijective, $(g \circ f)'(z) = x$. Thus $(g \circ f)'(z) = f'(g'(z))$ and the statement is proved.

Comment: The ' signifies the inverse?

Comment: Yes, that's what I intended. My apologies.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The proof is correct. ${}{}{}{}{}{}{}$